# Setting log.retentions.hours for broker in Kafka 0.10.2.x

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set `log.retenton.hours` for broker level configuration for kafka 0.10.2x. But I am getting this error for below command.

```
kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 --alter --add-config log.retention.hours=-1

Error while executing config command requirement failed: Unknown Dynamic Configuration 'log.retention.hours'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Unknown Dynamic Configuration 'log.retention.hours'.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
    at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$.$anonfun$validate$1(DynamicConfig.scala:101)
    at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$.$anonfun$validate$1$adapted(DynamicConfig.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1406)
    at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$.kafka$server$DynamicConfig$$validate(DynamicConfig.scala:100)
    at kafka.server.DynamicConfig$Broker$.validate(DynamicConfig.scala:59)
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.changeBrokerConfig(AdminUtils.scala:555)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:105)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:68)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, that property is not dynamic (cannot be modified while the broker is running)

Plus, that feature shouldn't be possible with your version

> From Kafka version 1.1 onwards, some of the broker configs can be updated without restarting the broker

You can set retention per topic level, otherwise, you need to edit the `server.properties` file of every broker and gracefully reboot them

I'm sure you have a good reason for "disabling" retention, but I would suggest trying compacted topics first

Comment: I am not disabling retention, I am doing infinite retention. It's because the data is being written in batches. Now when I restarted kafka gracefully I lost all previous messages and consumer got reset. I am using pyspark streaming Kafka . Any idea I can keep on appending to the existing place ?

Comment: You're disabling message expiration. Infinite retention is the same concept. Restarting brokers (just Kafka process, not the physical machine) doesn't "clear" the stored offsets or data of consumer groups, so I don't understand the problem. Perhaps you never committed the offsets of your consumer

Comment: As far as Spark issues are concerned, the documentation covers offset storage in Zookeeper, I believe

Comment: I store checkpoints in s3 inorder to save offsets, I was running Kafka in docker , I stopped kafka, and started it using run command. I was under the impression that the topics are saved on disk and would be retained even if I run a new docker kafka instance.

Comment: Umm, no. You might want to learn a bit more about Docker because any data that's not volume mounted will be gone immediately when you stop an instance. That applies to all containers

Comment: Also, if you're using Docker anyway, unless you're targeting an actual running Kafka 0.10 environment, I would suggest using a newer version

Comment: .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \, solved pyspark offset issue. Thanks, that solves my issues.

Answer (score 2):

`log.retention.hours` is read-only property at broker level, so it can't be changed using kafka-config.sh dynamically.

Change it in server.properties and restart the brokers.

Here are the details for readonly or dynamic broker config. 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs